# How to get SHAP values for each class on a multiclass classification problem in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, xgboost, shap

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

import xgboost
import shap

foo = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'var1':random.sample(range(1, 100), 10),
                   'var2':random.sample(range(1, 100), 10),
                   'var3':random.sample(range(1, 100), 10),
                   'class': ['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c']})
```

For which I want to run a classification algorithm in order to predict the 3 `class`es

So I split my dataset into train and test and I run an xgboost

```
cl_cols = foo.filter(regex='var').columns
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(foo[cl_cols],
                                                        foo[['class']],
                                                        test_size=0.33, random_state=42)


model = xgboost.XGBClassifier(objective="binary:logistic")
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Now I would like to get the mean SHAP values **for each class**, instead of the mean from the **absolute** SHAP values generated from this code:

```
shap_values = shap.TreeExplainer(model).shap_values(X_test)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test)
```

[image]

Also, the plot labels the `class` as 0,1,2. How can I know to which `class` from the original do the 0,1 & 2 correspond ?

Because this code:

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test,
                 class_names= ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

gives

[image]

and this code:

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test,
                 class_names= ['b', 'c', 'a'])
```

gives

[image]

So I am not sure about the legend anymore.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing some research and with the help of [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/explain-your-model-with-the-shap-values-bc36aac4de3d) and @Alessandro Nesti 's answer, here is my solution:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'var1':random.sample(range(1, 100), 10),
                   'var2':random.sample(range(1, 100), 10),
                   'var3':random.sample(range(1, 100), 10),
                   'class': ['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c']})

cl_cols = foo.filter(regex='var').columns
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(foo[cl_cols],
                                                        foo[['class']],
                                                        test_size=0.33, random_state=42)


model = xgboost.XGBClassifier(objective="multi:softmax")
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

def get_ABS_SHAP(df_shap,df):
    #import matplotlib as plt
    # Make a copy of the input data
    shap_v = pd.DataFrame(df_shap)
    feature_list = df.columns
    shap_v.columns = feature_list
    df_v = df.copy().reset_index().drop('index',axis=1)
    
    # Determine the correlation in order to plot with different colors
    corr_list = list()
    for i in feature_list:
        b = np.corrcoef(shap_v[i],df_v[i])[1][0]
        corr_list.append(b)
    corr_df = pd.concat([pd.Series(feature_list),pd.Series(corr_list)],axis=1).fillna(0)
 
    # Make a data frame. Column 1 is the feature, and Column 2 is the correlation coefficient
    corr_df.columns  = ['Variable','Corr']
    corr_df['Sign'] = np.where(corr_df['Corr']>0,'red','blue')
    
    shap_abs = np.abs(shap_v)
    k=pd.DataFrame(shap_abs.mean()).reset_index()
    k.columns = ['Variable','SHAP_abs']
    k2 = k.merge(corr_df,left_on = 'Variable',right_on='Variable',how='inner')
    k2 = k2.sort_values(by='SHAP_abs',ascending = True)
    
    k2_f = k2[['Variable', 'SHAP_abs', 'Corr']]
    k2_f['SHAP_abs'] = k2_f['SHAP_abs'] * np.sign(k2_f['Corr'])
    k2_f.drop(columns='Corr', inplace=True)
    k2_f.rename(columns={'SHAP_abs': 'SHAP'}, inplace=True)
    
    return k2_f

foo_all = pd.DataFrame()

for k,v in list(enumerate(model.classes_)):

    foo = get_ABS_SHAP(shap_values[k], X_test)
    foo['class'] = v
    foo_all = pd.concat([foo_all,foo])

import plotly_express as px
px.bar(foo_all,x='SHAP', y='Variable', color='class')
```

which results in [image]

Comment: The code doesn't work for me. So I tried fixing it as in my answer above. I still get some warning. I think the best would be you fixing them and post updated code in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question, perhaps this issue can help: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/764

I haven't tested it yet, but it seems the order should be the same as the order you would have when calling `model.predict_proba()`. In the link above it is suggested to use the `class_names=model.classes_` option of the summary plot.

Answer (score 2):

SHAP values are returned as a list. You can access the regarding SHAP absolute values via their indices.

For the summary plot of your Class 0, the code would be

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[0], X_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an updated code of @[quant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5868293/quant)'s code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

import numpy as np

import xgboost
import shap

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import plotly_express as px


foo = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'var1':random.sample(range(1, 100), 10),
                   'var2':random.sample(range(1, 100), 10),
                   'var3':random.sample(range(1, 100), 10),
                   'class': ['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c']})

foo['class'], _ = pd.factorize(foo['class'], sort = True)

cl_cols = foo.filter(regex='var').columns
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(foo[cl_cols],
                                                        foo[['class']],
                                                        test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

model = xgboost.XGBClassifier(objective="multi:softmax")
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

shap_values = shap.TreeExplainer(model).shap_values(X_test)







def get_ABS_SHAP(df_shap,df):
    #import matplotlib as plt
    # Make a copy of the input data
    shap_v = pd.DataFrame(df_shap)
    feature_list = df.columns
    shap_v.columns = feature_list
    df_v = df.copy().reset_index().drop('index',axis=1)
    
    # Determine the correlation in order to plot with different colors
    corr_list = list()
    for i in feature_list:
        b = np.corrcoef(shap_v[i],df_v[i])[1][0]
        corr_list.append(b)
    corr_df = pd.concat([pd.Series(feature_list),pd.Series(corr_list)],axis=1).fillna(0)
 
    # Make a data frame. Column 1 is the feature, and Column 2 is the correlation coefficient
    corr_df.columns  = ['Variable','Corr']
    corr_df['Sign'] = np.where(corr_df['Corr']>0,'red','blue')
    
    shap_abs = np.abs(shap_v)
    k=pd.DataFrame(shap_abs.mean()).reset_index()
    k.columns = ['Variable','SHAP_abs']
    k2 = k.merge(corr_df,left_on = 'Variable',right_on='Variable',how='inner')
    k2 = k2.sort_values(by='SHAP_abs',ascending = True)
    
    k2_f = k2[['Variable', 'SHAP_abs', 'Corr']]
    k2_f['SHAP_abs'] = k2_f['SHAP_abs'] * np.sign(k2_f['Corr'])
    k2_f.drop(columns='Corr', inplace=True)
    k2_f.rename(columns={'SHAP_abs': 'SHAP'}, inplace=True)
    
    return k2_f

foo_all = pd.DataFrame()

for k,v in list(enumerate(model.classes_)):

    foo = get_ABS_SHAP(shap_values[k], X_test)
    foo['class'] = v
    foo_all = pd.concat([foo_all,foo])

px.bar(foo_all,x='SHAP', y='Variable', color='class')
```

Answer (score 0):

The custom solution is an over-complication, IMHO.

**Solution**

```py
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test, class_inds="original", class_names=model.classes_)
```

**Explanation**

- pass over the class names to `summary_plot`. This has to reflect the order of predictions. Since one a priori doesn't know the order, then typically one can use `model.classes_` for that purpose;
- instruct `shap` to stick to the original order of predictions instead of sorting them: `class_inds="original"` (see the relevant code [here](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/45b85c1837283fdaeed7440ec6365a886af4a333/shap/plots/_beeswarm.py#L844-L848)).

P.S. I use `shap 0.40.0`

P.P.S. I was not able to run your example as my version of XGBoost doesn't allow to use strings as target categories. But it works with label-encoded target or with other model types (`sklearn.RandomForestClassifier` or `lgb.LGBMClassifier`)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use LabelEncoder and then classes_

```
import pandas as pd
import random

import xgboost
import shap
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

foo = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
               'var1':random.sample(range(1, 100), 10),
               'var2':random.sample(range(1, 100), 10),
               'var3':random.sample(range(1, 100), 10),
               'class': ['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c']})

cl_cols = foo.filter(regex='var').columns
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(foo[cl_cols],
                                                    foo[['class']],
                                                    test_size=0.33, 
                                                    random_state=42)

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
y_train_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(y_train.values.ravel())
y_test_encoded = label_encoder.transform(y_test.values.ravel())

model = xgboost.XGBClassifier(objective="multi:softprob", 
                              num_class=len(label_encoder.classes_))
model.fit(X_train, y_train_encoded)

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
classes = label_encoder.inverse_transform(range(
                            len(label_encoder.classes_)))
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test, class_names=classes)
```

[image]